# How to convert MM/YY to MM/DD/YYYY in Excel (missing day)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The day is missing so it just needs to be first of the month so:

11/17 would be 11/01/2017

Is there a formula that can do this?

Comment: Excel should already have done this for you. You just need to change the format of the cell.

Comment: The only reason it would format it like `MM/YY` is if you specifically asked it to. That being said, you can change it by just adjusting the formatting. Formula isn't necessary.

Comment: Is this a programming question? I am not sure you should be asking this on StackOverflow

Comment: The question is; Is this a true date?  When you click on the cell what do you see in the formula bar?  If you see `11/17` then it is a programming question, if you see a date that includes the day like `11/01/2017` then it is not and should have been asked on SuperUser.  If it is the prior you will want to parse the number and create the date using DATEVALUE

Comment: It doesn't have to be a programming question look at the tags they are `exel` and `exel-formula`  also if the formatting doesn't always work.  if you type 11/17 it will set it to 11/17/2017 but if you type 11/2017 it will give you 11/1/2017

Comment: Yes the data was already in MM/YY format. I'm trying to create a new column (or just edit the existing column) so it will be MM/DD/YYY with 01 as the DD. Changing the date format is not converting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two approaches:

1. Set the `Category` type of the cell (in `Format Cell`) as `Custom` and define this format in `Type` field: `mm/dd/yyyy`
2. In case of the format cell is text (working with string)

Assuming the validate entered in cell `A1`, use below formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,2)&"/01/"&IF(LEN(A1)=8,2,20)&RIGHT(A1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a stupid formula but it worked for me;

```
=DATE(100 + RIGHT(TEXT(A6,"MM/YY"),2),LEFT(TEXT(A6,"MM/YY"),2),1)
```

Try it out it takes the existing "MM/YY" format and converts it to a MM/DD/YYYY date using the date foromula `=DATE(Year,Month,Day)`.  It works if the date is in date format or text format.